# How to trigger retry for Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

According to Firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries and other pages,
I should  be able to trigger a retry in the code for the function to start again. But I have tried "throw new Error('Error message')" and "return Promise.reject(error)".
The function is never auto-triggered again. 
I have ticked the "Retry on failure" option in the Google Cloud console.
PS: The function is of Pub/Sub trigger type.